# If a sequence of Poisson RV's converges to $0$ show their parameters converge to $0$

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-distribution, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables such that $X_i \sim Poi(\lambda_i)$. If $X_n$ converges to $0$ almost surely show that $\lim_n \lambda_n = 0$.

If $X_n$ converges to $0$ almost surely, this implies

- $P(\lim_n X_N = 0) = 1$

Since the expectation of a poisson random variable is just its parameter, I was thinking of saying the parameters $\lambda_n$ must run to $0$ by the SLLN but the strong law only applies to a sample mean so now I have no idea where to start.

Comment: If $X_n\to0$ almost surely then $X_n\to0$ in probability hence, since every $X_n$ is integer valued, $P(X_n\ne0)=1-e^{-\lambda_n}\to0$, QED.

Comment: @Did I'm not entirely sure how you reached $P(X_n \not= 0) = 1 - e^{-\lambda_n}$ but I am working on it! It looks a lot like the complement of the distribution of $\lambda_n$ I'm just trying to figure out where the $\frac{\lambda_n^k}{k!}$ went